# Claims no TestMethod

Tags: c#, .net

Bom dia pessoal,
Estou iniciando em TDD no Visual Studio, e estou com problemas/dificuldades para passar as permissões de Claims na requisição que é realizada ao servidor.
Está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> Message: Test method MainTestes.Areas.Auxiliary.Controllers.AX001_CFOP.SvcControllerUnitTest.AutocompleteByCfopTest threw exception: System.InvalidOperationException: ID7024: Houve uma tentativa de uso do atributo ClaimsPrincipalPermission e possivelmente não há seção de configuração  definida. Consulte a exceção interna para obter detalhes. Além disso, certifique-se de que o elemento ClaimsAuthorizationManager esteja definido na seção

Abaixo o código do meu método de teste

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Realiza teste unitario no metodo AutocompleteByCFOP
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     Foi utilizado microsoft fakes para simular comunicação com request e como banco de dados para isolamento do codigo.
    /// </remarks>
    [TestMethod]
    [Owner("Julio")]
    [TestCategory("UnitTest")]
    [TestCategory("MainTests")]
    public void AutocompleteByCfopTest()
    {
        // Cria objeto de retorno do metodo fake
        var listCfop = new List<TechShop.Model.AX001_CFOP>
        {
            _ax001Cfop
        };

        // Classe fake para o manager
        var manager = new StubAX001_CFOPManager()
        {
            FindExpressionOfFuncOfAX001_CFOPBoolean = s => listCfop
        };

        // Cria um metodo Fake do HttpRequestMessage para substituir o request
        using (var request = new StubHttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.SetConfiguration(new HttpConfiguration());
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization",
                                "Bearer 0cr1oRh2byktwIXIDQspQtCkh-kmwZ716NwcfVoeUJ4HJ8mJ2X8FIHcBBRMF3K6I8AZcUYXj7RuvWoQrJm3V6AxGF3OIpxWZMOSwxNdxUVCmwZWZF2hju-tgAM5");

            using (var controller = new CFOPSvcController { Request = request, Manager = manager })
            {
                using (var response = controller.AutocompleteByCFOP(_ax001Cfop.AX001_ID.ToString(), _ax001Cfop.AX001_Type, _ax001Cfop.AX001_Origin))
                {
                    foreach (var item in (List<CFOPFormVM>)((ObjectContent)response.Content).Value)
                    {
                        Assert.AreEqual(item.ID, _ax001Cfop.AX001_ID);
                        Assert.AreEqual(item.Description, _ax001Cfop.AX001_Description);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Alguém já passou por isto ou sabe a solução para aplicar os Claims nos Testes?

Comment: E você fez o que mensagem da exceção sugeriu? "[...] possivelmente não há seção de configuração definida. Consulte a exceção interna para obter detalhes. Além disso, certifique-se de que o elemento ClaimsAuthorizationManager esteja definido na seção"

Comment: Sim, até mesmo inserir os "claims" manualmente.                     var claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "auxiliary-cfop:query;view;add;!edit;!delete") };
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, ClaimTypes.Role);
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    controller.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(principal);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola Julio Mendonça

Você precisa definir os elementos de claimsAuthorizationManager e identityConfiguration no seu arquivo de configuração de projeto (App.config), você deve informar as tag system.identityModel e system.identityModel.services no configSections.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /> 
    </configSections>
    <system.identityModel>
        <identityConfiguration>
            <claimsAuthorizationManager type="MainTests.Security.TestAuthorizationManager, MainTests" />
        </identityConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

Você deve definir o caminho da class que valida a autorização e o nome do projeto da classe no claimsAuthorizationManager.

Referências:

[https://forums.asp.net/p/2106526/6091223.aspx?Re+Performing+TestMethod+with+Claims](https://forums.asp.net/p/2106526/6091223.aspx?Re%20Performing%20TestMethod%20with%20Claims)

Comment: Acho valida sua observação, mas minha intenção é de dar os méritos para a pessoa que respondeu a pergunta, sem desmerecer o fórum que realmente solucionou o problema. Resposta será melhorada.

Comment: Tive que postar 4 à 5 vezes a resposta por que parte da minha resposta não estava sendo mostrada.

Comment: Entendi, agora meu comentário não faz sentido mais(felizmente :D) já que você editou a resposta, vou apagar pra não ficar poluindo o conteudo.

Comment: Podia remover o voto negativo também.